# How declare a generic class field inside abstract class

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to declare a generic field inside PakFileFormat class in order to be replaceable with concrete types in derived classes.

This will be fine:

```
public class Pak10File : PakFileFormat
{

    public Pak10File()
    {
        this.toc = new PakFileToc<Pak10FileEntry>();
    }
}
```

How to fix this ?
Thanks.

Related classes

```
public abstract class PakFileEntry { }

public class Pak10FileEntry : PakFileEntry
{
     public long size;                // 8 bytes
     public long csize;               // 8 bytes
     public long offset;              // 8 bytes
     public byte fname_len;          //  1 byte
     public char[] fname;             // variable
}  

public class PakFileToc<T> where T : PakFileEntry { }


public abstract class PakFileFormat
{       
    protected PakFileToc<T>; // ----- This does not compile.
}
```

Comment: `protected PakFileToc<SomeActualType> SomeActualFieldName;`

Comment: Or is that supposed to be the `toc` field? Are you saying that you want to declare a "generic" field in the sense of the reference not caring about the type parameter to `PakFileToc<T>`? You can't do that. That's not what C# generics are. The type parameter must be supplied at compile time. You can declare a non-generic base class to `PakFileToc` and use a reference to that. If possible, I recommend writing it such that you won't need to cast it to the actual parametered generic type in order to use it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I think you are not right at all. When you use generics, for example List<string> you see in IDE List<T> and you specify the string type at declaration. I am trying to achiveve this. Specifically restrict PakFileToc only to contain PakFileEntry children.

Comment: @ppk, so if you don‘t like the answer, the answerer must be wrong, even if the answer is correct?

Comment: @Sefe No. Maybe misunderstood what i want to do. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: @ppk  It is trivial to restrict your instance of PakFileToc only to contain PakFileEntry items (not children): Declare `protected PakFileToc<PakFileEntry> toc;` in the base class. If nobody is sure what you want to do, you need to work on clarifying your question.

Comment: @ppk, if you want to define a placeholder that gets implemented later on by different classes, you should not be using generics. What you're describing, is, instead, an interface situation. So declare an interface and away you go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make `PakFileFormat` generic also in order to make that compile.

In order for this to be useful though, you will probably need to make `PakFileFormat` implement some kind of *non-generic* interface.

It is hard to give more detail than this without knowing exactly what you need `PakFileFormat` to actually do, or how it will be used.

```
public abstract class PakFileFormat<TPakFile> where TPakFile : PakFileEntry 
{       
    protected PakFileToc<TPakFile> toc;
}
```

The sub-classes would then look something like:

```
public class Pak10File : PakFileFormat<Pak10FileEntry>
{    
    public Pak10File()
    {
        this.toc = new PakFileToc<Pak10FileEntry>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was trying. Ugliest but solves the trouble. The idea was write a class to deal with different file formats. This is why PakFileFormat, PakFileEntry are abstract. Just an empty container. And the real implementation is in specific classes.